# Row based Condition in Left Join

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to write a row based condition in Left Join.

If some row not exists based on column condition, then it should take the next first row.

I have the structure below,

```
create table Report
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)

create table ReportData
(
   report_id int references report(id),
   flag bit,
   path varchar(50)
)

insert into Report values (1, 'a');
insert into Report values (2, 'b');
insert into Report values (3, 'c');

insert into ReportData values (1, 0, 'xx');
insert into ReportData values (2, 0, 'yy');
insert into ReportData values (2, 1, 'yy');
insert into ReportData values (3, 1, 'zz');
insert into ReportData values (3, 1, 'mm');
```

I need some output like

```
1 a 0 xx
2 b 0 yy
3 c 1 zz
```

Comment: you need unique rows for each id in report table ?

Comment: What do you mean by "If some row not exists based on column condition". in your above example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
;WITH ReportDate_Rn AS (
   SELECT report_id, flag, path,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY report_id ORDER BY path) AS rn
   FROM ReportDate
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.flag, t2.path
FROM Report AS t1
JOIN ReportDate_Rn AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.report_id AND t2.rn = 1
```

The above query regards as *first* record of each `report_id` slice, the one having the *alphabetically smallest* `path`. You may amend the `ORDER BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,name,flag,path
FROM
(

SELECT Report.id,Report.name,ReportData.flag,ReportData.path,
       row_number() over(partition by ReportData.report_id order by flag) as rownum
FROM Report
JOIN ReportData on Report.id = ReportData.report_id
) tmp
WHERE tmp.rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative to the left join, using rowid and rownum

```
SELECT id, name, flag, path
FROM   report, reportdata 
WHERE  reportdata.rowid = (SELECT rowid 
                           FROM   reportdata 
                           WHERE  id = report_id 
                           AND    rownum = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `row_numner()` you can achieve this.

Have a look at this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82ef5/6)**

```
select r.id, r.name, d.flag, d.path from report r 
inner join reportdata d
on r.id = d.report_id group by d.report_id
```

*PS: I wasn't believing the result - I was just building the query - haven't used `d.report_id` in the `select clause` and it worked. Will be updating this answer once I get the reason why this query worked :)*

Answer (score 0):

Use **Partition BY**:

```
declare @Report AS table 
(
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
)

declare @ReportData AS table 
(
   report_id int ,
   flag bit,
   path varchar(50)
)

insert into @Report values (1, 'a');
insert into @Report values (2, 'b');
insert into @Report values (3, 'c');

insert into @ReportData values (1, 0, 'xx');
insert into @ReportData values (2, 0, 'yy');
insert into @ReportData values (2, 1, 'yy');
insert into @ReportData values (3, 1, 'zz');
insert into @ReportData values (3, 1, 'mm');

;WITH T AS 
(
    Select 
        R.id,
        r.name,
        RD.flag,
        RD.path,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY R.id ORDER BY R.id) AS PartNo
    FROM @Report R
    LEFT JOIN @ReportData RD ON R.id=RD.report_id
)
SELECT
    T.id,
    T.name,
    T.flag,
    T.path
FROM T WHERE T.PartNo=1
```